# Nginx & Docker: automatic proxy routing

Tags: docker, nginx, gunicorn

I have local nginx with many locations and proxy_pass for different projects. Most of my projects running in docker containers, which have WSGI configurations. 
During the creation of a new project and the launch of a new container, I have to manually modify the nginx configuration file for the new location and port.
How to automate the automatic change of the configuration file based on the docker container port?
Sorry for my English and thanks!

Comment: Hope help you - https://docs.traefik.io/

Comment: An other solution worth a read: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy